# mongoid embedded documents

Tags: ruby, mongoid, mongodb

i have some embedded documents. Company -> Stand -> Product. Document product have field "tag". I can do this request very well: `Company.where("stands.products.tags" => "books")`. But I want to find with two tag names, for example, `Company.where("stands.products.tags" => "books").where("stands.products.tags" => "toys")`. But in this example mongo will find only "toys tags". How I can find more tags in one request?

Comment: What is tags? Is it a string or array field?

Comment: It is string field, not array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you refactor your `tags` attribute into an array of strings, index them and then have a look at [this helpful method](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_in)

```
Company.any_in("stands.products.tags" => ["books", "toys"])
```